# Continuous time quantum walk on directed graph

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-spin

Continuous time classical random walk is described by probability vector $p(t)$ and generator matrix $Q$:
\begin{equation*}
\frac{dp(t)}{dt}=Qp(t)
\end{equation*}

Continuous time quantum walk is described by superposition state $\psi(t)$ and Hamiltonian $H$:
\begin{equation*}
\frac{d\psi(t)}{dt}=-iH\psi(t)
\end{equation*}

For example, a classical random walk on a 3-node graph is described by
\begin{equation*}
Q=\begin{bmatrix}-2&1&1\\1&-2&1\\1&1&-2\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
The corresponding quantum walk on the same graph is described by
\begin{equation*}
H=\begin{bmatrix}-2&1&1\\1&-2&1\\1&1&-2\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
Then we can compare the performance of classical walk and quantum walk.

However, the generator matrix is not necessarily symmetric. This corresponds to a directed graph. For example, node $i$ can go to node $j$ but node $j$ cannot go to node $i$, or it is easy to go from node $i$ to node $j$ but difficult to go from node $j$ to node $i$. For example, the classical walk may be described by
\begin{equation*}
Q=\begin{bmatrix}-3&2&1\\1&-2&1\\2&2&-4\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
In this case we can no longer set $H=Q$ since $H$ must be Hermitian (symmetric if all entries are real numbers).

Is the so-called nonHermitian quantum formulation pertinent to this? Or can we use the following two quantum walks to construct the quantum counterpart to the above $Q$?
\begin{equation*}
H_u=\begin{bmatrix}-3&2&1\\2&-3&1\\2&1&-3\end{bmatrix},
H_l=\begin{bmatrix}-3&1&2\\1&-3&2\\2&2&-4\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
We take the upper and lower part of $Q$ to make two symmetric $H$.

Maybe we can start from approximating an asymmetric generator with two symmetric generator.

My question: Is there any idea about constructing the quantum counterpart to the asymmetric continuous time classical walk?

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use Hermitian adjacency matrix to study continuous time quantum walk on a directed graph.
For example, We consider a directed graph $D$. Let $M$ denote the 0-1 adjacency matrix of graph $D$, we know that the 0-1 adjacency matrix of a directed graph is skew symmetric. When M is multiplied by an imaginary number $i$, $H=iM$ is Hermitian matrix. Then we can use $H$ to study the continuous time quantum walk.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).